# Python Django image upload API with 6 fixed slots

Tags: python, django, sqlite, rest-framework

I built an image upload API with Python Django. There are a fixed number of 6 slots, which can either be null or filled with something. There are two entities, Profile, which contains the six photos, and an overridden save method. The other entity involved is Upload, which contains the timestamp when it was uploaded at, and the file which is an ImageField.

The magic happens in `views.py` where the `/users/profile/` request is processed. This request takes in optional image parameters `photo1`, `photo2`, `photo3`, ..., `photo6`. If one of these photo slots in the request are already filled, it calls the `swap_photos()` function which deletes the current photo from both the `mediafiles/` directory and the Upload entity in the SQLite database, then creates a new photo in place of the deleted photo. The save process is quite complicated to avoid any ForeignKey constraint errors which I spent a considerable amount of time troubleshooting. Here is my code:

`views.py:`

```py
def swap_photos(photo_obj, new_photo_val, user_profile, photo_id):
    """Deletes the photo in the old reference and adds the photo in the request"""
    Upload.delete(photo_obj)

    if photo_id == 1:
        user_profile.photo1 = Upload.objects.create(file=new_photo_val)

    elif photo_id == 2:
        user_profile.photo2 = Upload.objects.create(file=new_photo_val)

    elif photo_id == 3:
        user_profile.photo3 = Upload.objects.create(file=new_photo_val)

    elif photo_id == 4:
        user_profile.photo4 = Upload.objects.create(file=new_photo_val)

    elif photo_id == 5:
        user_profile.photo5 = Upload.objects.create(file=new_photo_val)

    elif photo_id == 6:
        user_profile.photo6 = Upload.objects.create(file=new_photo_val)


@api_view(['POST', 'PUT'])
def profile_create_or_update(request):
    """Creates or updates a profile"""
    user_profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()

    # Photo logic
    if 'photo1' in request.data:
        if user_profile.photo1 is not None:
            swap_photos(user_profile.photo1, request.data['photo1'], user_profile, 1)
        else:
            photo1 = Upload.objects.create(file=request.data['photo1'])
            user_profile.photo1 = photo1

    if 'photo2' in request.data:
        if user_profile.photo2 is not None:
            swap_photos(user_profile.photo2, request.data['photo2'], user_profile, 2)
        else:
            photo2 = Upload.objects.create(file=request.data['photo2'])
            user_profile.photo2 = photo2

    if 'photo3' in request.data:
        if user_profile.photo3 is not None:
            swap_photos(user_profile.photo3, request.data['photo3'], user_profile, 3)
        else:
            photo3 = Upload.objects.create(file=request.data['photo3'])
            user_profile.photo3 = photo3

    if 'photo4' in request.data:
        if user_profile.photo4 is not None:
            swap_photos(user_profile.photo4, request.data['photo4'], user_profile, 4)
        else:
            photo4 = Upload.objects.create(file=request.data['photo4'])
            user_profile.photo4 = photo4

    if 'photo5' in request.data:
        if user_profile.photo5 is not None:
            swap_photos(user_profile.photo5, request.data['photo5'], user_profile, 5)
        else:
            photo5 = Upload.objects.create(file=request.data['photo5'])
            user_profile.photo5 = photo5

    if 'photo6' in request.data:
        if user_profile.photo6 is not None:
            swap_photos(user_profile.photo6, request.data['photo6'], user_profile, 6)
        else:
            photo6 = Upload.objects.create(file=request.data['photo6'])
            user_profile.photo6 = photo6

    user_profile.save()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

`photos/models.py:`

```py
class Upload(models.Model):
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file = models.ImageField()


    @property
    def is_valid(self):
        """
        A photo is valid if the datetime flag has value
        """
        return bool(self.uploaded_at)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Upload, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
        os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.file.name))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            super(Upload, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name
```

`users/models.py:`

```py
import datetime

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ValidationError

from photos.models import Upload

from .enums import get_choices, ReligionConstants, PoliticsConstants, \
    ChildrenStatusConstants, EthnicityConstants, SeekingConstants, PetsConstants, \
    AlcoholConstants, SmokingConstants, MarijuanaConstants, EducationLevelConstants


def age_from_birthday(birthday: datetime.date, /) -> int:
    return (datetime.date.today() - birthday).days // 365


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email was not set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user)
        profile.save()
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('location', {"town": "Jackson", "state": "New Jersey",
                                "country": "United States of America", "latitude": 40.09188, "longitude": -74.35875})

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """User characteristics that aren't expected to change often"""
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=16, default="")

    class Gender(models.TextChoices):
        MALE = "MALE", 'Male'
        FEMALE = "FEMALE", 'Female'

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=Gender.choices)

    @property
    def age(self) -> int:
        return age_from_birthday(self.birthday)

    def age_validator(birthday):
        if not age_from_birthday(birthday) >= 18:
            raise ValidationError(_("User must be over 18"))

    birthday = models.DateField(validators=[age_validator])

    likes = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
    # LocationField()  # Town, State, Country, Latitude, Longitude
    location = models.JSONField(default=dict)
    # {"town": "Jackson", "state": "New Jersey", "country": "United States of America", "latitude": 40.09188, "longitude": -74.35875}

    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    force_reset_password = models.BooleanField(
        default=False, verbose_name="Force reset password on next login")

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'birthday', 'gender']

    objects = UserManager()


class Profile(models.Model):
    """User characteristics that are expected to change often"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    photo1 = models.ForeignKey(Upload, related_name='photo1', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    photo2 = models.ForeignKey(Upload, related_name='photo2', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    photo3 = models.ForeignKey(Upload, related_name='photo3', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    photo4 = models.ForeignKey(Upload, related_name='photo4', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    photo5 = models.ForeignKey(Upload, related_name='photo5', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    photo6 = models.ForeignKey(Upload, related_name='photo6', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    seeking_choice = models.CharField(choices=get_choices(SeekingConstants), default=SeekingConstants.BOTH_MEN_AND_WOMEN, null=True, blank=True, max_length=18)
    ethnicity = models.CharField(choices=get_choices(EthnicityConstants), null=True, blank=True, max_length=27)
    children_status = models.CharField(choices=get_choices(ChildrenStatusConstants), null=True, blank=True, max_length=25)
    religion = models.CharField(choices=get_choices(ReligionConstants), null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    politics = models.CharField(choices=get_choices(PoliticsConstants), null=True, blank=True, max_length=12)
    pets = models.CharField(choices=get_choices(PetsConstants), null=True, blank=True, max_length=7)
    alcohol = models.CharField(choices=get_choices(AlcoholConstants), null=True, blank=True, max_length=9)
    smoking = models.CharField(choices=get_choices(SmokingConstants), null=True, blank=True, max_length=9)
    marijuana = models.CharField(choices=get_choices(MarijuanaConstants), null=True, blank=True, max_length=9)
    education_level = models.CharField(choices=get_choices(EducationLevelConstants), null=True, blank=True, max_length=28)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.photo1 is not None:
            self.photo1.save()

        if self.photo2 is not None:
            self.photo2.save()

        if self.photo3 is not None:
            self.photo3.save()

        if self.photo4 is not None:
            self.photo4.save()

        if self.photo5 is not None:
            self.photo5.save()

        if self.photo6 is not None:
            self.photo6.save()

        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`photos/models.py:`

```py
import os

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

# Create your models here.
class PublicMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    default_acl = 'public-read'
    file_overwrite = False


class Upload(models.Model):
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file = models.ImageField()


    @property
    def is_valid(self):
        """
        A photo is valid if the datetime flag has value
        """
        return bool(self.uploaded_at)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if os.environ.get('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE') == 'config.settings.local':
            super(Upload, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
            os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.file.name))
        elif os.environ.get('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE') == 'config.settings.dev':
            super(Upload, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
            # os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.file.name))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            super(Upload, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name
```

What are some more efficient ways to write this code out for both increased readability, maintainability, performance, and security if necessary?

Comment: Please show your SQLite definitions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a SQLite definition.

Comment: SQL DDL that defines the structure of your SQLite database.

Comment: Can I just show you all of my models.py files? @Reinderien

Answer (score 1):

> more efficient ways to write this code out for both increased readability, maintainability ?

My goodness!
Bet your keyboard looks like `[Z][X][C][ ][B]`,
with the `V` markings rubbed off by repeated paste paste paste.

When you see repetition,
ask how you can parameterize or refactor.

[Guido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum)
gave us `list`s and `dict`s -- use them!

---

## setattr

```
def swap_photos( ...
    if photo_id == 1:
        user_profile.photo1 = Upload.objects.create(file=new_photo_val)
    ...
    elif photo_id == 6:
        user_profile.photo6 = Upload.objects.create(file=new_photo_val)
```

All the `if`s boil down to `if photo_id in range(1, 7):`, that's easy.
(Or you might prefer `if 1 <= photo_id < 7:`.)

I *will* grant you that if we retain this API exactly
it might seem a little hard to parameterize.
The magic builtin that we use less often than a `dict` is called
[setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).
Here, you can use

```
    setattr(user_profile, f"photo{photo_id}", Upload.objects.create(file=new_photo_val))
```

---

## items()

In `profile_create_or_update`
it appears you want to loop over some dictionary items and use the
[getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) builtin:

```
import re

photo_re = re.compile(r"^photo\d+$")
...
def profile_create_or_update( ...

    for k, v in request.data.items():
        if photo_re.search(k):  # key looks like "photo" with numeric suffix
            if (photo := getattr(user_profile, k, None)) is not None:
                swap_photos(photo, v, user_profile, 1)
            else:
                photo = Upload.objects.create(file=v)
                setattr(user_profile, k, photo)
```

I confess that all those {get,set}attr calls
are a little inconvenient.
Maybe we could convince `user_profile` to offer a nicer Public API?
Or we might prefer to maintain a `dict`
which we then copy into `user_profile` at the last moment.

---

## positional_or_keyword

```
def age_from_birthday(birthday: datetime.date, /) -> int:
    return (datetime.date.today() - birthday).days // 365
```

Ummm, you kind of lost me there with
the `/` [slash](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter).
There's a [PEP-570](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570)
thing going on here, where you're prohibiting
caller from mentioning `... , some_name=42)` arguments.
Except that, there's no more parameters after the slash.
I don't get it.
The slash only seems useful if it's followed by one or more params.
Recommend you delete it, or (minimally) that you describe
the motivation in a comment.

Also, nit, *some* years have `365` days.
For people who have managed to make it through at least
one year of primary school, we tend to see them racking up
the occasional February 29th. There's lots of
[details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Gregorian_calendar).
You did great by accessing a timedelta's `.days` property. Better to examine a
[relativedelta's](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html)
`.years` property.
Then we report accurately,
even on days near the person's birthday.

---

## schema design

Imagine one day the marketing director walks in and announces
that "tomorrow we have to launch a **seventh photo** feature!"
Or eight photos or some other nightmare integer.
In how many places will we need to adjust the code?
Yeah. Quite a few.
I suspect the design took a turn for the worse
when we started using six columns in a certain table.

Consider [normalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)
the DB design so there's a table entirely devoted to photos, with
[FK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)
pointing back to profile.

Now the bits of {getattr, setattr} ugliness above disappear,
and adjusting max photos could involve editing
just a single line of code.

---

This is pretty OK code.
I didn't see anything terrible in it.
It just suffers from too much repetitive pasted source text.

This code appears to achieve its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.